# Meaning of 'rut' in 'Rut he will not, nor will you.'

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

There is a piece from *Maurice* by E M Forster where I can not quite get the usage of 'rut'. What is it there for?

> "Rubbish?" He questioned Maurice, who, when he grasped the point, was understood to reply that deeds are more important than words.
> "What is the difference? Words are deeds. Do you mean to say that these five minutes in Cornwallis's rooms have done nothing for you? Will you ever forget you have met me, for instance?"
> Chapman grunted.
> "**Rut he will not, nor will you**. And then I am told we ought to be doing something."
> The Dean came to the rescue of the two Sunningtonians. He said to his young cousin, "You're unsound about memory. You confuse what's important with what's impressive. No doubt Chapman and Hall always will remember they've met you —"
> "And forget this is a cutlet. Quite so."
> "Rut the cutlet does some good to them, and you none."
> "Obscurantist!"

Comment: It looks like a mis-print and should probably be 'But".

Comment: Well, it might make sense. But twice - lucky me to get caught on it

Comment: What text was this? It looks like text that has been digitized and put through image recognition software. Badly. If you put Maurice or Forster in the title and give some guidance to chapter/page, you might get a passing Forster fan who'll look it up in a proper print edition.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an obvious OCR error of [***But** he will not*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22But+he+will+not+%2C+nor+will+you%22) - not to mention ***rut** the cutlet does some good* a couple of sentences further on.

Comment: Given the context, I shudder to think what 'rut the cutlet' could mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED:

> **2. a**. *intransitive*. **Of a deer or other animal:** to be under the influence of periodic sexual excitement; to take part in the annual rut. **Also: to copulate.**
>
> 1600   W. Vaughan Nat. & Artific. Direct. Health vi. i. 61   *The fields waxe greene, hearbes and flowers doe bud, beastes rut, the birds chirp.*
>
> 1889   E. Westermarck Orig. Marriage 49   T*he buck and the ass in southern countries..rut throughout the whole year.*
>
> 1974   J. A. Michener Centennial iii. 58   *When he rutted he simply climbed on the back of his mate, locking his forepaws about her.*

Either that, or it is a misprint for "**B**ut"

Comment: You might get away with the sexual interpretation in "Rut he will not", however, "Rut the cutlet does some good to them" is almost certainly an indication that it's a misprint.

Comment: @KillingTime I was going on the subject matter of the book for "rut". ;)